# Counting the number of "li" elements in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have to count the number of `li` elements present in a `div`.
Below is the HTML section of the web page:

[image]

I have written the following lines of code to count the tiles:

```java
public void configButtonCount()
{
    WebElement button= driver.findElement(By.className(".config-category"));
    List<WebElement> buttonCount = button.findElements(By.xpath("//li"));
    System.out.println("List size is: " +buttonCount.size());
}
```

Can anyone tell me why is it being displayed as `Unable to locate element: .\.config\-category"`

Also, the right line of code?

Comment: There is also another class for that div - ng-scope. Either use both classes or use css etc. Also the //li xpath needs a dot in front of it,else it will return all the li instead of those inside the div...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you have a period (.) in the class name, `.config-category`. The class name does not contain a period in the HTML. I think you are confusing this with CSS selectors where you preface the class name with a period.

You can write a single locator to find all the `LI`s that you are looking for using CSS selectors. You are looking for `DIV`s that contain the class name `config-category` which you can represent as `div.config-category`. Next you want descendants of that `DIV` that are `LI`s. Descendants are represented with a space and then you add `li` like, `div.config-category li`. The code below should work.

```
public void configButtonCount()
{
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.config-category li"));
    System.out.println("List size is: " + buttons.size());
}
```

CSS selectors are extremely powerful locators and are widely supported and have very good performance, especially vs. XPath locators. I would suggest that you take some time to read up on them and learn the basics. You will find them extremely useful. Here are just a couple resources to get you started:

[W3C CSS selectors reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS selectors tips & tricks](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)